# How do I link an image to its own page?

Tags: templating, assets, routes

I'm new to Craft CMS and can't figure out how to link images with the code below to its own page. Any suggestions?

```
{% for asset in entry.mainImages %}

    <a href="{# link to the image's page #}">
        <img src="{{ asset.url('thumb') }}">
    </a>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Craft assets do not get "their own page" by default, but you can easily create them with a [Dynamic Route](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes). So go to Settings → Routes and add a new route with a number token, e.g. `assets/<number>` and route those URIs to a new template, e.g. `assets/_entry`.

With this route set up you can now link to an asset's entry page like so:

```
<a href="{{ url('assets/' ~ asset.id) }}">
    <img src="{{ asset.url('thumb') }}">
</a>
```

In your assets/_entry.html template you do now [query for your asset](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.assets) via its ID, which is now available as a variable named "number". Use the [`exit`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/exit) tag to 404 the request in case no asset was found for the given ID.

```
{% set asset = craft.assets.id(number).first() %}

{% if not asset %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

<figure>
    <img src="{{ asset.url('fullscreen') }}">
    <figcaption>{{ asset.caption }}</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what exactly you mean by 'its own page'

Do you want to have an entry for each image? or a twig template that displays that image?

When you access a page by default `{{ entry.url }}` refers to the entry of the page you are currently on.

You can link to the `{{ asset.url }}` but I'm not certain that is what you are trying to achieve.

Please update your question so we can help you further.